# put our money in

Tags: meaning

In my Red Rock Mystery Book there is the text:

> I knew the trip would be an adventure, but I'd had no idea we'd get to go to my favorite restaurant on the planet - Carson's. I could almost taste their ribs and coleslaw as we reached the ticket kiosk. The problem was, neither Ashley nor I knew how to work it. The directions were confusing, and farther up people crowded through turnstiles.
>
> I was about **to put a couple of dollars in** when Ashley got a CTA (Chicago Transit Authority) attendant's attention. I told him we wanted to stop at Carson's restaurant downtown before heading to Ridgefield.
>
> "Ah, great choice." He **put our money in** and told us which trains to take and when to use the tickets.

I'm intersted in "put in" phrase. In the first place I can understand meaning of "put a couple of dollars in" (the meaning is - I mentioned we have some money and we can use it in that situation). TheFreeDictionary.com and Collins dictionary tell the same on that. By in the second place I can't understand "put our money in". Author wants to tell that attendant took the money? or he simple refused to take the money? or something else? I don't know anything about Chicago attendants but I can guess he saw kids before him and refused to take money though they offered it.

Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the context, which is difficult if you have never seen it before: They put money in the slot of a **ticket kiosk**. There is a slot, you put your money in, select a ticket and it then dispenses the ticket through another slot. They didn't know how to work it.

*to put money in [the slot of] a ticket kiosk*. The one below is for buying tickets. A dictionary does not help here because the author did not bother to repeat the term ticket kiosk, so the reader is left with the impression that "put in" is a phrasal verb, which, in fact, it isn't here.

From Soft Logic
[image: ticket kiosk]

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would find that usage of 'kiosk' confusing. To me, a kiosk is a little enclosed cabin with a person inside, behind a window or opening, ready to answer enquiries or sell newspapers, tickets, snacks, etc. The thing in your picture I would call a 'machine', and the type that sells rail tickets a 'ticket machine'. Real UK rail buffs and staff call them TVMs (Ticket Vending Machines).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, Michael, yes. It means both things in AmE but obviously in the context of this paragraph, it is about buying tickets from a machine and not buying newspapers from a punter. UK site: https://www.touch-screen-kiosk-systems.co.uk/ticketing-kiosk/what-is-a-ticket-kiosk/ If you scroll down the page of this site, you will see it is *très British".

Comment: As an AmE speaker, when I hear "kiosk" I usually think of a little enclosed booth too, not a machine.

Comment: @stangdon I am going by the text as posted by the OP.  Also, kiosk as a stand-alone machine has been around for a while **in American English**. MW: 
: a small stand-alone device providing information and services on a computer screen
a museum with interactive kiosks [another example of a kiosk]

Comment: Frankly, I think anyone reading this answer should agree with it. It is not my fault if kiosk is used in various ways.

Comment: Yes, that machine is often called a kiosk in AmE. However, I don't understand why you say "gambling". It looks like the one in the picture is offering tickets to music concerts.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, I will remove that. I had another one at first and changed it and it was a gambling kiosks. There are all sorts of kiosks. **I cannot believe that all of you are not agreeing with me. In the OP's text, this is a ticket kiosk and the characters state they put their money in it.** Where is the problem?? It's in the dictionary, it's in the picture, it's in the text. My goodness.

Comment: Easy, now, Lambie! Steady on!